# How can I count files in folder and subfolder using Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, get-childitem

I am trying to count all files in subfolder and extract to csv. Here is the file structure.

```
C:\TEST\FolderAAA

  |-folderA1
     |-folderA1.1
        |-file
        |-file
     |-folderA1.2
        |-file
        |-file
     |-folderA1.3
        |-file
        |-file

   |-folderA2
     |-folderA1.1
        |-file
        |-file
     |-folderA2.2
        |-file
        |-file
     |-folderA2.3
        |-file
        |-file

C:\TEST\FolderBBB

  |-folderB1
     |-folderB1.1
        |-file
        |-file
     |-folderB1.2
        |-file
        |-file
     |-folderB1.3
        |-file
        |-file

   |-folderB2
     |-folderB2.1
        |-file
        |-file
     |-folderB2.2
        |-file
        |-file
     |-folderB3.3
        |-file
        |-file

C:\TEST\FolderCCC

  |-folderC1
     |-folderC1.1
        |-file
        |-file
     |-folderC1.2
        |-file
        |-file
     |-folderC1.3
        |-file
        |-file

   |-folderC2
     |-folderC2.1
        |-file
        |-file
     |-folderC2.2
        |-file
        |-file
     |-folderC3.3
        |-file
        |-file
```

I am looking for a CSV output with the below format:

```
Column A          Column B
Folders           File Count
----------------------------
FolderAAA                   0
folderA1                    0
folderA1.1                  2
folderA1.2                  2
folderA1.3                  2
folderA2                    0
folderA2.1                  2
folderA2.2                  2
folderA2.3                  2

Space/New Blank Row --------

FolderBBB                   0
folderB1                    0
folderB1.1                  2
folderB1.2                  2
folderB1.3                  2
folderB2                    0
folderB2.1                  2
folderB2.2                  2
folderB2.3                  2

Space/New Blank Row --------

FolderCCC                   0
folderC1                    0
folderC1.1                  2
folderC1.2                  2
folderC1.3                  2
folderC2                    0
folderC2.1                  2
folderC2.2                  2
folderC2.3                  2
```

I tried and modified this code that I found after doing some research here:

```cs
$FOLDER_ROOT = "C:\TEST\"
$OUTPUT_LOCATION = "C:\TEST\RESULT\Folder_Count.txt"
$OUTPUT_CSV = "C:\TEST\RESULT\Folder_Count.csv"

function DirX($directory) {
    Remove-Item $OUTPUT_LOCATION

    foreach ($singleDirectory in (Get-ChildItem $directory -Recurse -Directory)) {
        $count = Get-ChildItem $singleDirectory.FullName -File |
                 Measure-Object |
                 %{$_.Count}
        $summary = $singleDirectory.Basename + " - " + $count
        Add-Content $OUTPUT_LOCATION $summary
    }
}
DirX($FOLDER_ROOT)

Import-Csv $OUTPUT_LOCATION -Delimiter "-" -Header Folder, Count |
    Export-Csv $OUTPUT_CSV -NoTypeInformation
```

The extract I am getting does not format according to what I am trying to achieve.

Currently the extract is formatted incorrectly this way:

```
Column A          Column B
Folders           File Count
----------------------------
FolderAAA                  0
folderA1                   0
folderA2                   0
folderA1.1                 2
folderA1.2                 2
folderA1.3                 2
folderA2.1                 2
folderA2.2                 2
folderA2.3                 2
```

Comment: It appears that using `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory` traverses the directory structure using _breadth first search_. This is the root cause of why the output shows up in the order AAA -> A1, A2 -> etc.. One solution is to perform the traversal yourself by implementing a depth first traversal algorithm.

Comment: Thanks Josh, I am afraid this is too technical for me. I am still a beginner with Powershell. Would there be a guide or reference for me to do some research somewhere that you could recommend? Thanks again.

Comment: Traversals are a fun topic that typically gets covered in the first year of a computer science curriculum at highschool or university. It's a beginner friendly topic when covered on its own; unfortunately, most of the material online when you search "depth first search" assumes you're working with binary trees, and uses the language of graphs, edges, leafs, and nodes, instead of speaking directly about directories and files as you're working with in your problem.

You might find some luck exploring the topic by searching, `"depth first" + "traversal" + "directories" -graph` on google?

Comment: Thanks Josh for the guidance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I concur with [@Scepticalist's suggested approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57687662/1630171), but would recommend streamlining it into a pipeline, like this:

```
Get-ChildItem $FOLDER_ROOT -Recurse -Directory |
    Sort-Object FullName |
    Select-Object FullName, @{n='Count';e={(Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -File).Count}} |
    Export-Csv -Path $OUTPUT_CSV -NoType
```

Comment: Thanks Ansgar - I made the updates based on your suggestions to @Scepticalist approach

Answer (score 1):

Why not gather the data first, then sort it and output?

```
$FOLDER_ROOT = "C:\TEST"
$OUTPUT_CSV = "C:\TEST\Folder_Count.csv"

Function DirX($directory) {
    Write-Host "Working..." -NoNewline
    $Data = Get-ChildItem $directory -Recurse -Directory | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host "."-NoNewline
        $count = (Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -File).count #  | Measure-Object | %{$_.Count}
        [pscustomobject]@{FilePath = $_.fullName;Filecount = $count}
    }
    Write-Host "Done"
    $Data | Sort-Object Filepath
}


$ThisPath = Dirx $FOLDER_ROOT
$ThisPath | Export-Csv -Path $OUTPUT_CSV -NoTypeInformation
```